# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded when reading large PDF file using itext PdfReader

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to read a pdf file using PDFReader and re-sequence of pages. It's working with PDF with smaller size but when the size exceeds > 200MB. It fails with below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.clean(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.close(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.close(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.close(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I am using itext java 2.1.7 version

Comment: Needs debugging details: code and PDF. Also, iText 2.1.7 is over a decade old and is very much not supported any more.

Comment: Also you might want to check how much heap memory you have allocated for your JVM & profile it using something like VisualVM.

Comment: Yes itext 2.1.7 is way too old but due to licensing part for commercial use, I cannot compromise using this version

Comment: What Java version do you use? Do you already use -Xmx VM parameters and if so what are they?

Comment: Yes we do have -Xmx parameter defined which is 2048m & I observed it crashes if value is set below 4096m

Comment: please share the java code part where you are reading this file from input stream

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding heap memory of the running Java with **-Xmx**.

Take a look at https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control/ to know how Xmx is used.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the heap memory using `-Xmx` might help (as suggested by Pablo) but you should also look at your code and see why it produces that amount of garbage and why your code skims just below the "out of memory" mark. This could be the sign of broken code.